# How Can I add recent chats in SQL table called recentchats?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

**Admins / Mods Chill I Can't Ask New Questions That's why I'm Hi-Jacking Old Ones According to @DarkBee**

So in my project admin and the staff members can chat with each other by sending messages along with the application and keep submitting new messages to talk with each other it's not dynamic both sides have to refresh page in order to see new message (Not Simultaneously).

so the staff members account can send messages from their page (view-applicant-form.php) to admin and it loads on admins page (all-form.php) without any issue but from admins side I Can send the message but it only goes to the SQL table called recentchat and the code I've written is not being able to fetch the messages of the admin.

Can anyone please take look at my code and explain to me how can I fix it?

view-applicant-forms relevant part of code :

```
if(isset($_GET['message'])) {
$taskId = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['id']);
$tinfoq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE 
id='$taskId'");
$tdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tinfoq);
// Check if the task data is retrieved successfully
if ($tdata) {
task data
$estfid = $tdata['stfid'];
$wstfid = $tdata['assign'];
// If assign is 0, set wstfid to 0
if ($wstfid == 0) {
$wstfid = $estfid;
$estfid = $tdata['assign'];}
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['message']);
$sendq = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `recentchat`(`estfid`, 
`wstfid`, `echat`, `taskid`, `taskchatid`) 
 VALUES ('$estfid', '$wstfid', '$message', '$taskId', 
'{$tdata['id']}')");
if ($sendq) {
echo "<script>window.open('view-applicant-form?id=$taskId', 
'_self')</script>";
} else {
echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);}
}else{echo "Error: Task not found.";}}
```

html part :

```
<div class="box box-danger direct-chat direct-chat-danger">
<div class="box-header with-border">
<h3 class="box-title">Recent Chat<?php 
//print_r($_GET['message']);
$tinfoq=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE 
id='".trim($_GET['id'])."'");
$tdata=mysqli_fetch_assoc($tinfoq);
?></h3>
<div class="box-body">
<!-- Conversations are loaded here -->
<div class="direct-chat-messages">          
<?php 
$chatq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM recentchat 
WHERE'".$tdata['taskid']."' AND (wstfid='".$tdata['stfid']."' || 
wstfid='".$tdata['assign']."') AND (estfid='".$tdata['stfid']."' 
 || estfid='".$tdata['assign']."')  AND taskchatid 
 ='".$tdata['id']."' ");
while ( $chatdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chatq)) {
# code...
?><?php if(!empty($chatdata['echat'])){?>
<button class="btn btn-warning pull-right"><!--Sales--><?php 
 echo $chatdata['echat']?></button>
<br><br/><p class="pull-right"> <?php echo date("M/d/Y, h:i A ", 
 strtotime($chatdata['etime']));//echo $chatdata['wtime'];?></p> 
<br><br/><br/><br/><br/><?php }?>  <?php 
if(!empty($chatdata['wchat'])){?><?php //print_r($chatdata)?>
<button class="btn btn-info pull-left"> <!--Work--><?php echo 
$chatdata['wchat']?></button><?php echo '<br><br>'.date("M/d/Y, 
h:i 
A ", strtotime($chatdata['wtime']));//echo $chatdata['wtime'];?> 
<br/><br/><br/><?php }?>
<?php }]] ?></div></div>
</div><div class="box-footer">
<form action="#" ><div class="input-group">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];? 
 >">
<input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type Message ..." 
class="form-control">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn- 
flat">Send</button>
</span></div></form></div>\</div></div>
```

& here's the code for all-form.php page :

```
<?if (isset($_GET['message'])) {
$tinfoq=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE 
id='".trim($_GET['id'])."'");
$tdata=mysqli_fetch_assoc($tinfoq);
//print_r($tdata);$MyPHPStringVar=1;
$sendq=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `recentchat`( 
`estfid`,`wstfid`, `echat`, `taskid`,`taskchatid`) VALUES 
('".$tdata['stfid']."', 
'".$tdata['assign']."','".trim($_GET['message'])."', 
'".$tdata['taskid']."','".$tdata['id']."')");
//$MyPHPStringVar=1;
 echo "<script>
 window.open('view-applicant?id=".trim($_GET['id'])."','_self') 
 </script>";
  } ?>
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <style type="text/css">
  </style><br>
  <div class="box box-danger direct-chat direct-chat-danger ">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
  <h3 class="box-title">Recent Chat<?php 
  $tinfoq=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE 
  id='".trim($_GET['astaskid'])."'");
  $tdata=mysqli_fetch_assoc($tinfoq);
  // echo isset($_GET['message']);?></h3>
  </div><div class="box-body">
  <div class="direct-chat-messages ">
  <?php 
  $chatq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM recentchat WHERE 
  taskid='".$tdata['taskid']."' AND (wstfid='".$tdata['stfid']."' 
  || wstfid='".$tdata['assign']."') AND 
  (estfid='".$tdata['stfid']."' || estfid='".$tdata['assign']."') 
   AND taskchatid ='".$tdata['id']."'");
   while ( $chatdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chatq)) {?>
   <?php if(!empty($chatdata['wchat'])){?>   <button class="btn 
   btn-info pull-right"><!--Work--><?php echo $chatdata['wchat']?> 
   </button> <br><br/> <p class="pull-right"> <?php echo 
   date("M/d/Y, h:i A ", strtotime($chatdata['wtime']));//echo 
   $chatdata['wtime'];?></p> <br><br/><br/><br/><br/><?php }?>  <? 
   phpif(!empty($chatdata['echat'])){?>
  <button class="btn btn-warning pull-left"><!--Sales--> <?php 
  echo $chatdata['echat']?></button>
  <?php //print_r($chatdata)?>
  <?php echo '<br><br>'.date("M/d/Y, h:i A ", 
  strtotime($chatdata['etime']));//echo $chatdata['wtime'];?><br/> 
  <br/> 
  <br/><br/><?php }?> 
  <?php } ?>
   </div>
   </div></div>
   <div class="box-footer">
   <form action="#" >
   <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type Message 
    ..." class="form-control">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn- 
   flat">Send</button>
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo 
   $_GET['id'];?>"></span></div></form></div></div>
```

Comment: If you are having trouble with errors relating to code that isn't even there any more - then most likely you either did not upload the modified version of your script file correctly, or you have some sort of caching issue.

Comment: I solved it thanks to caching Thank you! Can you please tell me how can i make this a dynamic site so that I can edit the pages of my theme into elementor for adding some other features in it [like woo commerce products, customer reviews using any plugin etc]?

Comment: Please don't "hi-jack" an old question to ask a new question - Instead ask a new question...

Comment: FYI: Your code is open for [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: @DarkBee I'm banned from asking new questions that's why I'm Hi-Jacking old ones. I know this whole project is full of sql injections that's why I need help with it in is not my project and my company has asked me to stop worrying about it and make it work.

Comment: "*I'm banned from asking new questions*" ... Please take the time to read [ask]. If you keep doing this, chances are your account will just be put to inactive

Comment: @DarkBee go ahead do it'll create a new account... just trying to play by the rules of this site.....

Comment: Which apparently you're not

Comment: what do you mean? @DarkBee